# Is HTTP auth an impediment for a server side Google Maps reverse geocoding API call

Tags: php, google-maps, ip

In my php app I use google's reverse geocoding service.  It works fine on localhost, where the url is myproject.ryan.com.  But if I test on the staging server, which is at an IP address (we have no domain yet) and has HTTP auth password protection, the reverse geocoding doesn't work.  It's the same code, so this must be related to either the use of IP or the auth prompt, I would guess.  I wonder if there is something I need to do in the console.

The code...

```
// Format this string with the appropriate latitude longitude.
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=' . $latlng . '&output=json&sensor=true_or_false&key=' . APP_KEY;

// Make the HTTP request.
$data = @file_get_contents($url);

// Parse the json response.
$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
```

Comment: Take a look here for how to use HTTP authentication with file_get_contents: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-authentication-and-filegetcontents-457.html

Comment: Just as a comment, for staging it's fine, but limiting access to a free maps api site would likely be against the terms of service. You might also look into client side geocoding, this article may be helpful: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geocodestrat.html

Comment: GoldenNewby -- That article is for situations where the file you are fetching is protected.  In my case it's my own script that's protected.  I'm now assuming this doesn't matter, since Google is not making a request from my server during the reverse geocode.

Comment: Mano, correct, it's for staging only.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't have allow_url_fopen turned on in php.ini.  Ooops!  With that switched on, my app works.  Apparently neither the HTTP auth or my use of an IP address are any kind of impediment at the moment (during development).  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Since your server is making the call, the problem shouldn't be with the authentication. My guess is that it is your `sensor=true_of_false`, should be `sensor=true` or `sensor=false`. Another possibility is your key is IP restricted in someway. Check the developer console.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see that.  It appears to have been a non-factor in this case.  Anyways I have changed it to false.  Thx for catching that.